# Joomla Module View Access Level Issue

Tags: module, acl

I am working on joomla and I am having a situation. I have created 2 Custom HTML modules.

a). Certified Membership Subscription Box (Disabled) b). Certified Membership Subscription Box (Enabled)

Both have almost the same piece of code in them except the color of the button (one is green, other is gray).

Now I have two user groups

a). Associate Members

b). Associate Members (Passed)

I created 2 access levels for both groups.

a). Associate Membership Exam (Non-Passed) --------> Having view rights to Associate Members Group

b). Associate Membership Exam (Passed) --------------> Having view rights to Associate Members (Passed) Group

I want users in "Associate Members" to see Certified Membership Subscription Box (Disabled) module only and users in "Associate Members (Passed)" to view Certified Membership Subscription Box (Enabled).

I assigned access level Associate Membership Exam (Non-Passed) to Certified Memebership Subscription Box (Disabled) module. And Associate Membership Exam (Passed) access level to Certified Memebership Subscription Box (Enabled) module.

I have displayed both modules in an article by using {loadposition cert_mem_sub_box_enabled}{loadposition cert_mem_sub_box_disabled}.

Now in last when I try to log in by users from each group it shows only the Certified Memebership Subscription Box (Disabled) module (all the time). I don't know what's going on. Modules are not being shown/hidden according to user group/access level.

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just a few quick thoughts and questions to help you troubleshoot this:

- Login as a Super User and see if both modules are displayed and what are their colors.
- If they don't appear both of them, then something lies in the module ability to display in that page (publish state, menu assignment, module position/calling, etc).

If they both appear to a Super User, then:

- Do both modules have the same exact content?
- If the above answer is yes, then how do you apply the different color to them? If through external CSS, then it is possible that there is a CSS override that turns gives one color to any of the modules being displayed. It can help you to distinguish the modules, by changing a bit their text.
- Review again the access levels and that you are actually checking with the appropriate user.

Try the above and if you don't come to a conclusion, report back.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem might be that Viewing levels are 'implicit'.  So it depends on which parent level you used when creating the View Level.  Suppose for example you created a View Level 'MyPub'  with parent 'Publisher'.  Anyone in a group assigned to 'MyPub' would also see items with View Levels Publisher, Editor, Author, Registered and Public.

There is no way of switching this 'inclusiveness' off for View Levels.

Also the usual default when you create a User Group is that you also get to be implicitly a member of the parent  chain of groups.  For groups this can be switched off with a call to the relevant core function but I do not know of any component, module or plugin that makes use of explicit or implicit group membership.